# Password masking with a batch file and problem with displaying polish characters

Tags: batch-file, character-encoding, passwords, masking

I wrote such a code. Its purpose is to enter the masked password and proceed if the password is correct. It worked, but what I cannot deal with is displaying Polish characters after entering the password. Because as a result of the code I want a text with the characters `ęąćóżź` and I get `eacozz`. Is there a way to be able to display these types of characters after executing such code?

```
@echo off
:start
chcp 65001 >nul
echo ęąćóżź
timeout 4
CALL:InputPassword "Password" p
IF !p!==examplepassw (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    GOTO continue ) ELSE (
        CLS
        GOTO start
        )
:InputPassword
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host '%1' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set %2=%%p
)
GOTO :eof   
:continue
echo ęąćóżź
pause>nul
```

Comment: I thought that the Polish code page was 852, so why don't you try using that instead of the critically limited UTF-8 code page 65001.

Comment: Using a code page other than 65001 doesn't display Polish characters. Using chcp 852 I see this `─Ö─ů─ç├│┼╝┼║`  instead of `ęąćóżź`

Comment: Those characters are all included in code page 852, i.e. 0xA9, 0xA5, 0x86, 0xA2, 0xBE, 0xAB. As you've manually typed those characters into your batch file, did you also save that batch file with the same encoding, i.e. code page 852? If you didn't then surely what you typed into the text file will be translated/converted when `echo`ed from the script code page to the newly defined one.